# Long exact cech cohomology sequence for quasicoherent sheafs on separated quasicompact schemes

Tags: algebraic-geometry, sheaf-cohomology

Let $X$ be a scheme with an finite affine open covering $\mathcal{U} = (U_i)_{i=1}^k$ such that all intersections of $U_i$'s are affine too. Why does a short exact sequence of quasicoherent $\mathcal{O}_X$-modules
$$ 0 \to \mathcal{F} \to \mathcal{G} \to \mathcal{H} \to 0$$
induces a short exact sequence
$$ 0 \to C^q(\mathcal{U},\mathcal{F}) \to C^q(\mathcal{U},\mathcal{G}) \to C^q(\mathcal{U},\mathcal{H}) \to 0$$
where $C^q(\mathcal{U},\mathcal{F}) = \prod_{i_0 < \ldots < i_q} \mathcal{F}(U_{i_0} \cap \ldots \cap U_{i_q})$ is the Cech-Complex?

This is an intermediate step to show that a short exact sequence of quasicoherent sheafs on a separated quasicompact sheaf induces a long exact cech-cohomology sequence.

**What I've tried:**
I know that $H^q(U_{i_0} \cap \ldots \cap U_{i_q},\mathcal{F}) = 0$ since the intersection is affine and $\mathcal{F}$ is quasicoherent, so Leray's theorem tells me that $H^q(X,\mathcal{F}) = H^q(\mathcal{U},\mathcal{F})$. However this does not help with the $C^q$, does it? Or is this something much simpler?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You essentially already found the reason yourself: For any $i_0<\ldots<i_q$ you have an exact sequence $$0\to{\mathscr F}(U_{i_0}\cap\dots\cap U_{i_q})\to {\mathscr G}(U_{i_0}\cap\dots\cap U_{i_q})\to{\mathscr H}(U_{i_0}\cap\dots\cap U_{i_q})\to\text{H}^1(U_{i_0}\cap\dots\cap U_{i_q};{\mathscr F}),$$
and the last term vanishes since $U_{i_0}\cap\dots\cap U_{i_q}$ is affine. Hence, you get a short exact sequence
$$0\to{\mathscr F}(U_{i_0}\cap\dots\cap U_{i_q})\to {\mathscr G}(U_{i_0}\cap\dots\cap U_{i_q})\to{\mathscr H}(U_{i_0}\cap\dots\cap U_{i_q})\to 0,$$
and taking the product over all choices of $i_0<\ldots<i_q$ gives the exact sequence you are after.

Comment: Cool, so it works because taking finite products is exact.

Comment: @legacytron: Yes, and since you are taking products of abelian groups, infinite products would be fine as well.

Comment: That sounds interesting, but I don't quite understand. Would I have to check by hand that taking products is exact or is there some nice argument?

Comment: @legacytron: It's a distinguished feature of abelian categories with a projective generator, like module categories - but you can of course also check it by hand. Note that without the assumption of enough projectives, even the nicest (locally Noetherian Groethendieck) categories such as $\text{QCoh}({\mathbb P}^1_{\mathbb k})$ fail to have exact products.